# what is the command for + on top of -

Tags: symbols, positioning

I would like to have + on top of -, I used stackrel, overset, underset, but nothing is close to what I see in textbooks, is there a specific command that places the + very close to the - underneath?

Comment: Do you mean `\pm`?

Comment: `\pm` for plus-minus, `\mp` for minus-plus.